# How would I read a list from text file?

Tags: python

I tried this:

```
saves = open('filename','r')
Y = saves.readlines()
print(Y)
```

but I get the output `[b'[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]']` instead of `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]`

The text file content is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

(This not duplicate as the question is about something else and the answer didn't help me)

Comment: Could you share text file content ?

Comment: of course will edit the question now

Comment: you can transform data by this way: Y = [eval(x) for x in Y]

Comment: prints it like this   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]]

Comment: @DenisKuzin `eval` is never a good method to use, in any situation.

Comment: Ast.literal_eval does the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Json module.

```
import json
Y = json.load(open('filename','r'))
print(Y)
```

Output

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> open('f.txt', 'w').write('[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]')
>>> y = json.load(open('f.txt', 'r'))
>>> y
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: that throws up lot's of errors

Comment: @Qwertykey Might want to be specific about those errors... :)

Comment: Expecting value: line 1 column 16 (char 15) - that's the error

Comment: @Qwertykey Yeah I got it. Your text file has an extra `,` (comma). Observe: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]`
                    (this last comma needs to go.)

Comment: still prints with double brackets

Comment: @Qwertykey In that case, your text file contents are different from what you claim them to be. I have tried this with the exact same input you mentioned in your post and got exactly what I put in my answer. Henceforth, please be clear with your question.

Comment: in the text file it literally just says [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: @Qwertykey I've edited my post to add a demo. Please try it out and see what you get. Which python are you using? In the worst case just do `Y[0]` to remove the double brackets.

Comment: your method works, i forgot to change something and that's why the error happened

Comment: @Qwertykey Ah, no worries. Happens to us all.